# Audio diff tool

Tags: audio, diff

Example: I have two versions of one song, and one of them misses some parts. I want to see which parts are missing and which are different.

I see interface of such program as two adjacent waveforms, moved apart and highlighted in places of differences. In other words, audio equivalent of diff/merge text tools interface.

- Platform: desktop
- Preferably cross-platform
- Preferably Free and Open-Source Software, but I'll consider other options too

Comment: FYI a related question regarding merging: [Program to merge two MP3s](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2393/903).

Comment: This is actually a proposed feature for Audacity: [Proposal Audio Diff - Audacity Wiki](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Proposal_Audio_Diff)

Comment: Another dupe: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22849/is-there-a-diff-tool-for-audio?newreg=228cd5048d5e47399f9220dabf18389f

Comment: I have a similar case... Someone posted two versions of an interview of more than an hour (differing with 20 minutes) and I'm wondering where they differ.. (lossy compressed files) (youtube content ID seem to have this figured out)

Answer (score 5):

Download and install [python](http://www.python.org), [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), [graphplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and [audiolab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.audiolab/) you can then:

- Load audio files into numpy arrays using audiolab.
- Diff the arrays.
- Plot the result.
- Learn a lot... *it's all free*

Comment: PLOT the result. You can learn a LOT..

Comment: Surely this might only work for losslessly compressed files? (and even then, finding shifted segments are significantly more complicated than "diff the arrays")

Comment: @GertvandenBerg The process above does decompress the signal but you are correct that there will be some difference if lossy compression has been used - in that case some filtering &/or minimum difference levels will be needed. The above does have the facilities for that but it will require some user experimentation for how close is close enough hence the plotting stage.

Comment: I'm thinking that building something based on chopping the files up and using [phash](https://www.phash.org/) on parts (shifted by various amounts in case they don't start at the same time) might work... (Not very simple to implement though...) There might also be some uses for convolution functions... None of that is simple though...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg there is a set of python bindings for libphash.