# Difference of audio files

Tags: windows, audio

I am looking for a tool that can automatically analyze the difference of two audio signals that I record from a microphone.

The software must

- auto align the audio sample start position. I can provide a test tone or click to indicate the beginning.
- process standard file formats (e.g. WAV, 44 kHz, mono)
- subtract one signal from the other and save the result in a standard file format (e.g. WAV, 44 kHz, mono, uncompressed)
- optional: display the result (but I can use other tools like Audacity for that)
- run on Windows (7 x64 and 10 x64)
- cost < 100 €

My request is similar to [Audio Diff Tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/audio-diff-tool), except

- my recordings do not miss parts. There is no need to detect cut or moved parts. Basically my recordings are of the same length with some additional silence (could be noisy) at the beginning and at the end.
- no need to be gratis or open source
- no need for cross-platformness

The [answer there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3622/9295) could possibly apply for my case as well, but I'd like to avoid programming it myself because neither me nor my colleagures are very familiar with audio processing, so developing such a tool is error-prone.

I tried

- [Audio Diff Maker](http://www.libinst.com/Audio%20DiffMaker.htm), but comparing one file to itself resulted in a difference, which is unexpected.